# Decode NTLM Authorization packet?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am creating a web site that must use Windows authentication via an Active Directory server.   This is in dotnet core 2 running on Linux/Docker.

I can successfully call up the Windows login via the browser, and I get an NTLM authorization header.

I have an LDAP library I can use to verify credentials.

The bit I'm stuck with, is the NTLM authorization header contains a uuencoded 'blob', and the library requires domain/user/password.

I have found [this page](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html), which describes the contents of the NTLM blob, but I feel it would be better if I don't have to decode it.

After a bit of [digging,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) it looks like SASL might take the NTLM blob, but the library I have doesn't support it.

Comment: There are no credentials stored there, that's the whole point. *The OS* validates the user and gives him a "ticket" that all other machines on the same domain can recognize and validate, possibly against the domain controllers. That's how Kerberos works BTW.

Comment: If you want to implement single-sign on, LDAP credentials are *not* the correct way. That's the simple "login for each separate service" scenario. Kerberos (or a federation mechanism) on the other hand can be used to give the user a ticket at the first login that can be used when talking to any service.

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that if I decode the username/domain from the 'blob' it must already be authenticated (assuming the hashes are correct).

Comment: Not at all. After all, would you *accept* any random header that says the user is `MyDomain\Administrator` without *verifying* it? What about replay attacks, would you accept a 1-day old ticket?

Comment: Good point.  So how do I verify that the token came from the correct server, and is still valid?

Comment: What you ask is already implemented by various packages for specific servers, eg [for Apache](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Authenticating_Apache_against_Active_Directory). Perhaps you should use another server as a reverse proxy for your web site. Or you could use a different authentication mechanism. [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) can work with different providers that implement WS-Federation or OpenID

Comment: See this project http://github.com/kztao/SharpCifs